# Find all pixels bounded between two contours in a binary image in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, binary

I have a binary image, like the one shown below, which has two contours shown in white,

[image]

I wish to make all the pixels in between the contours white some thing like below,

[image]

How can I do this in Python using Numpy or OpenCV or Scipy?

I currently use FloodFill as shown below,

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
# read image
seed = [377,273]
rep_value = (255, 255, 0)
ImageDraw.floodfill(img, seed, rep_value, thresh=50)
img.save(f'cloud_floodfill_{seed}.png')
```

But here I need to provide a `seed` value. I have thousands of images like this one where the two contours can be translated anywhere. How to automate the process for several images.

I guess OpenCV's FloodFill will also have the same limitation.

Comment: possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322652/how-to-fill-color-correctly-in-closed-curve-using-opencv-python)

Comment: You can use `drawContours()`, example here https://medium.com/featurepreneur/draw-contours-on-an-image-using-opencv-186b67f87c92

Comment: how were those lines made?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz they are provided by a annotator.

Comment: invert (edit: maybe not, trouble with connectivity), so areas are objects, lines divide them. find contours with hierarchy. walk hierarchy.  take note how the hierarchy works and that it is ***doubled*** in your case (explore the data to learn what I mean because I can't explain this without showing you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach:

- `findContours`
- **walk the hierarchy**
- make new contours list
- draw it

The hierarchy **for this specific configuration**, when walked, will contain:

- outline outer contour
- outline inner contour
- "inline" outer contour
- inline inner contour

You want an area between the outline inner contour and inline outer contour.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(im, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# hierarchy is a vector<Vec4i> -> row vector of Vec4i, so (1,N,4), weird shape
hierarchy = hierarchy.squeeze(0) # remove that 1-dimension
```

```
composite = im.copy()

outline_outer = 0
outline_inner = hierarchy[outline_outer, 2]
inline_outer = hierarchy[outline_inner, 2]

new_contours = [contours[outline_inner], contours[inline_outer]]

cv.drawContours(image=composite, contours=new_contours, contourIdx=-1, color=255, thickness=cv.FILLED)
```

[image: output]

[image: illustration]

This illustration was done by drawing into a BGR version, with red, and then overlaying the source to make it look pretty.

The approach can be extended to arbitrary numbers and nestings. It just takes more work to walk the hierarchy. *Edit: [a similar question asked for this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76080129/2602877)*